# sqlite3 syntax error that I cannot find

Tags: sqlite, python-2.x

The line of code is the following:

```
conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE summury (set , avarageApproxAlg1Opt, optFound, maxApprox, range1, range2, range3, range4);''')
```

It's in a Python script and it complains about my sintax:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "set": syntax error
```

I'm not experienced in SQL and I cannot understand what's wrong there.
Sorry for the quality of the question, but.. any help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set` is a keyword in SQL. Either rename the column, or put it in `"double quotes"`.

Comment: .... I realize only now that, in my attempts, I thought about that, but I substituted `set` with `group` without any idea that 'group' was also a keyword. Damn, thanks a lot for the double quotes hint!